# unittest.Mock - Combining return_value and side_effect

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Is it possible to have a `Mock` object return a value when called as well as execute a statement when called? For example this:

```
> mocked_func = Mock(return_value='Returned foo', 
                     side_effect=lambda: print('Side effect executed')
                    )

> print(mocked_func())

Side effect executed
None
```

The documentation seems a little ambiguous here but it seems to me that when `side_effect` is used, then `return_value` is ignored altogether and only the result of `side_effect` function is returned (which in case of `print()` is `None`).

Since Python does not really support multi-statement lambdas (AFAIK, the best you can do is put expressions in a tuple, but then the whole tuple would be returned) - is it possible to combine the two arguments?

I want to avoid having to define a new function and using that as the `side_effect`, I feel having both declared in a `Mock` is cleaner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to "is it possible to have a `Mock` object return a value when called as well as execute a statement when called?" is obviously yes, just make `side_effect` do everything:

```
import unittest.mock as mock

def side_effect():
      print('Side effect executed')
      return 'Returned Foo'

mocked_func = mock.Mock(side_effect=side_effect)

print(mocked_func())

# output
Side effect executed
Returned Foo
```

Of course you can do it with a lambda too:

```
import unittest.mock as mock

mocked_func = mock.Mock(
    side_effect=lambda: (print('Side effect executed'), 'Returned Foo')[1]
)

print(mocked_func())

# output
Side effect executed
Returned Foo
```

It does not look any cleaner to me but to each their own. If you just want to avoid polluting your namespace you can do this:

```
def mocked_func():
    print('Side effect executed')
    return 'Returned Foo'
mocked_func = mock.Mock(side_effect=mocked_func)
```

Or using a decorator:

```
def mock_it(f):
    return mock.Mock(side_effect=f)

@mock_it
def mocked_func():
    print('Side effect executed')
    return 'Returned Foo'
```

Combining `return_value` and `side_effect` does not seem to be possible as you already noticed.

Answer (score 2):

requires python version >=3.3

0) `import unittest.mock.DEFAULT`

1) Make the `side_effect` function returns `DEFAULT`

```
def func():
    print('I am func(), and side_effect() called me!!')
    return  DEFAULT
```

4) Create the mock

```
 nice_print = 'I am a return value that side_effect() cannot override because 
               side_effect() returns special obj called DEFAULT'
 mocked_func = mock.Mock(side_effect=func, return_value=nice_print)
```

3) goodluck :)