# What happens when a python mock has both a return value and a list of side effects?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, python-unittest.mock

I'm having trouble understanding what's happening in some test code. It looks like this:

```py
import pytest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
from my_module import MyClass

confusing_mock = MagicMock(
    return_value=b"",
    side_effect=[
        ConnectionError(),
        b"another_return_value?",
        b"another_another_return_value?"
    ])

mocked_class = MyClass()
monkeypatch.setattr(mocked_class, "method_to_call_thrice", confusing_mock)
```

I know that:

- `side_effect` is a function to be called whenever the mock is called
- but if `side_effect` is an iterable, then "each call to the mock will
  return the next value from the iterable" (thanks [pytest
  docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect))
- the docs also say that if the function passed to `side_effect`
  returns `DEFAULT`, then the mock will return it's normal value from
  `return_value`

But here's what I don't get:

- What happens when I provide **both** a **list of side effects** and a
  **return value**?
- What should I expect to see on each call of `MyClass.method_to_call_thrice`?

Comment: The question "[unittest.Mock - Combining return_value and side_effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47176726/unittest-mock-combining-return-value-and-side-effect)" seems related, but I'm still not quite getting it.

Comment: You could try with a simple return valeu and a simple side effect and see what happens?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`side_effect` is used. A list value can contain `mock.DEFAULT`, and a function can return `mock.DEFAULT`, to indicate that the value of the `return_value` attribute be used.

```
>>> import unittest.mock
>>> m = unittest.mock.Mock(return_value="foo",
...                        side_effect=[1, 2, unittest.mock.DEFAULT, 4, 5])
>>> m()
1
>>> m()
2
>>> m()
'foo'
>>> m()
4
>>> m()
5
>>> unittest.mock.Mock(return_value="foo",
...                    side_effect=lambda: unittest.mock.DEFAULT)()
'foo'
```

Comment: To remove an already present `side_effect`, you can also set it to `None` (per the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock))