# How to set mocked exception behavior on Python?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, exception, pytest, pytest-mock

I am using an external library (github3.py) that defines an internal exception (github3.exceptions.UnprocessableEntity). It doesn't matter how this exception is defined, so I want to create a side effect and set the attributes I use from this exception.

Tested code not-so-minimal example:

```
import github3

class GithubService:
    def __init__(self, token: str) -> None:
        self.connection = github3.login(token=token)
        self.repos = self.connection.repositories()

    def create_pull(self, repo_name: str) -> str:
        for repo in self.repos:
            if repo.full_name == repo_name:
                break
        try:
            created_pr = repo.create_pull(
                title="title",
                body="body",
                head="head",
                base="base",
            )
        except github3.exceptions.UnprocessableEntity as github_exception:
            extra = ""
            for error in github_exception.errors:
                if "message" in error:
                    extra += f"{error['message']} "
                else:
                    extra += f"Invalid field {error['field']}. " # testing this case
            return f"{repo_name}: {github_exception.msg}. {extra}"
```

I need to set the attributes `msg` and also `errors` from the exception. So I tried in my test code using pytest-mock:

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_github3_login(mocker: MockerFixture) -> MockerFixture:
    """Fixture for mocking github3.login."""
    mock = mocker.patch("github3.login", autospec=True)
    mock.return_value.repositories.return_value = [
        mocker.Mock(full_name="staticdev/nope"),
        mocker.Mock(full_name="staticdev/omg"),
    ]
    return mock


def test_create_pull_invalid_field(
    mocker: MockerFixture, mock_github3_login: MockerFixture,
) -> None:
    exception_mock = mocker.Mock(errors=[{"field": "head"}], msg="Validation Failed")
    mock_github3_login.return_value.repositories.return_value[1].create_pull.side_effect = github3.exceptions.UnprocessableEntity(mocker.Mock())
    mock_github3_login.return_value.repositories.return_value[1].create_pull.return_value = exception_mock
    response = GithubService("faketoken").create_pull("staticdev/omg")

    assert response == "staticdev/omg: Validation Failed. Invalid field head."
```

The problem with this code is that, if you have `side_effect` and `return_value`, [Python just ignores the return_value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56191199/what-happens-when-a-python-mock-has-both-a-return-value-and-a-list-of-side-effec).

The problem here is that I don't want to know the implementation of `UnprocessableEntity` to call it passing the right arguments to it's constructor. Also, I didn't find other way using just `side_effect`. I also tried to using return value and setting the **class** of the mock and using it this way:

```
def test_create_pull_invalid_field(
    mock_github3_login: MockerFixture,
) -> None:
    exception_mock = Mock(__class__ = github3.exceptions.UnprocessableEntity, errors=[{"field": "head"}], msg="Validation Failed")
    mock_github3_login.return_value.repositories.return_value[1].create_pull.return_value = exception_mock
    response = GithubService("faketoken").create_pull("staticdev/omg")

    assert response == "staticdev/omg: Validation Failed. Invalid field head."
```

This also does not work, the exception is not thrown. So I don't know how to overcome this issue given the constraint I don't want to see the implementation of `UnprocessableEntity`. Any ideas here?

Comment: You're supposed to use either the [return_value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.return_value) attribute if you want your mocked function to consistently return the same value or the [side_effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) attribute if you want your mocked function to return an iterable or raise an exception. A mocked function which defines both makes no sense. Also, what are you trying to test exactly? Testing doesn't really make sense if you are mocking every inputs :/

Comment: Your minimal example is not self-contained - in your code you call `repo.create_pull` (and use a non-existent variable `github_repo`), but in the test you mock `github3.login` - did you want to mock `github3.repos.ShortRepository`?

Comment: You are right @MrBeanBremen I updated the code to make it more complete. Hope it is better now.

Comment: You are right @jeremyr.. from this definition I needed side_effect since I need an exception. But, I need to find a way to use the exception attributes to make my output message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on your example, you don't really need to mock [github3.exceptions.UnprocessableEntity](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py/blob/master/src/github3/exceptions.py#L287) but only the incoming [resp](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py/blob/master/src/github3/exceptions.py#L103) argument.

So the following test should work:

```py
def test_create_pull_invalid_field(
    mocker: MockerFixture, mock_github3_login: MockerFixture,
) -> None:
    mocked_response = mocker.Mock()
    mocked_response.json.return_value = {
        "message": "Validation Failed", "errors": [{"field": "head"}]
    }

    repo = mock_github3_login.return_value.repositories.return_value[1]
    repo.create_pull.side_effect = github3.exceptions.UnprocessableEntity(mocked_response)
    response = GithubService("faketoken").create_pull("staticdev/omg")

    assert response == "staticdev/omg: Validation Failed. Invalid field head."
```

**EDIT:**

If you want [github3.exceptions.UnprocessableEntity](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py/blob/master/src/github3/exceptions.py#L287) to be completely abstracted, it won't be possible to mock the entire class as catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed (See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html)). But you can get around it by mocking the constructor only:

```py
def test_create_pull_invalid_field(
    mocker: MockerFixture, mock_github3_login: MockerFixture,
) -> None:
    def _initiate_mocked_exception(self) -> None:
        self.errors = [{"field": "head"}]
        self.msg = "Validation Failed"

    mocker.patch.object(
        github3.exceptions.UnprocessableEntity, "__init__", 
        _initiate_mocked_exception
    )

    repo = mock_github3_login.return_value.repositories.return_value[1]
    repo.create_pull.side_effect = github3.exceptions.UnprocessableEntity
    response = GithubService("faketoken").create_pull("staticdev/omg")

    assert response == "staticdev/omg: Validation Failed. Invalid field head."
```

Comment: this solution works but relies on the implementation of the exception. I don't know if there is other way arround. If no one elses come to a solution that doesn't use it, I will accept this as the correct one.

Comment: @staticdev I edited the answer to cover your use case. Abstracting exception is always a bit tricky as it cannot be caught properly if not derived from BaseException, but it is possible to only mock the constructor method.

Comment: I think this second version is a more "pure" unit test although a bit trickier as you said, but that is perfect to me. I would also add the first one marked as integration/end-to-end. Thanks a lot @jeremyr.